# Selectize not playing nice with form inputs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, selectize.js

So I am using [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) and and I am doing it as such:

```
  $('#tags').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    create: function(input) {
        return {
            value: input,
            text: input
        }
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that I get the following when the page loads

[[image: ]]

And then when I enter in some text and hit enter I get:

[[image: ]]

I am unsure why this is happening, I am using twitter bootstrap 3.1.x and I am using the bootstrap 3 version of this library. I am unsure why this is behaving this way - the console has no errors what so ever. Any one know what I am doing wrong?

even just `$('#tags').selectize();` does the same thing

Comment: It looks like you're missing the Selectize stylesheet?

Comment: @brianreavis ++1, I had a similar issue and your comment helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the bootstrap3 theme from the selectize dist directory.

https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/tree/master/dist/css/

Answer (score 0):

you might have a different "select" plugin installed like Materialize or the bootstrap js? Remove these and check the result.